# Yii2 Button url to folder

Tags: php, url, pdf, button, yii2

I want to create a button which opens a pdf. This pdf is in another folder, but I can't reach this folder. Can somebody help me, I'm quite new to this.

Here is my Button:

```
$button = Html::a('Geef document weer', ['/uploads/documenten/' . $model->documents[0]->location . '/' . $model->documents[0]->file . $model->documents[0]->format], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 'target' => '_blank']);
```

Comment: do u want to download pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use hash notation  but specify the link and in 'yourPath' set the proper value

```
 $button = Html::a('Geef document weer', 
 'yourPath/uploads/documenten/' . $model->documents[0]->location . '/' . $model->documents[0]->file . $model->documents[0]->format, 
 ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 'target' => '_blank']);
```

or   use @web alias

```
 $button = Html::a('Geef document weer', 
    Url::to('@web/uploads/documenten/')  . $model->documents[0]->location . '/' . $model->documents[0]->file . $model->documents[0]->format, 
 ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs', 'target' => '_blank']);
```

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge, This was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Write out the link without using the html helpers

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Something like <a href="my/path" . $model->documents[0]->location . '/' . $model->documents[0]->file . $model->documents[0]->format] . "" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" target="_blank">Click here </a>